# A single leaf in a very strange air current / wind?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Here is my eight years old movie where I have pictured a single leaf moving in a very weird way:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCjvgdfNCjU

Can someone explain me what is depicted in this movie (what process, event or situation) or otherwise what is causing this single leaf to move there and back in such way / pattern?

By listening to the sound or observing other leaves (barely moving) you can assume that this isn't a wind what is causing leaf to move. There was also nothing in the kind of spider web or no animal around that could influence leaf's movement.

The movie was captured in late September 2011 in southwest Poland, near Jedlina Zdrój [in a forest on the hillsides of the "Mały Wołowiec" mountain](https://goo.gl/maps/WP7oK6YEbZP4CkWL6) (approx. 50°44'22.5"N 16°18'28.7"E).

Note: *I understand that this question maybe considered a trivia, downvoted or even closed, yet it depicts one of my personal really weird biology-related mysteries, I ever run into. So, I'd really would like to know, what is going on here?*